# FME Tester, Value does not equal

Tags: workspace, fme-form

I have a workspace where I am writer multiple databases to a new file geodatabase with many tables. If there is a spelling error in a value I do not want it to go through. The issue is I have about 20 fields with up to 30 values where there could be an error. For example, the DATUM field has to equal NAD27 or NAD83 **NOT** NAD 27 or NA D83..

Given I have many fields and many values, is there an easy way to direct these values != to the values I need. I just don't want to create a tester with 100+ lines where the value doesn't equal. Is there an easier way, one that would decrease the time to run the workspace. (It already takes 3-4 hours to run).

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to attempt this, or two that I would start with.

The first is the AttributeValueMapper transformer. There you can map bad values to good. You still need to enter values, but it's not as complicated a setup as the Tester would be.

The second solution is the SchemaMapper transformer. You could then keep your spelling mistakes as a list in a text or CSV file. Check out [this article](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1159/schemamapper-use-case-example.html). I think you would want example 10 in the list there.